# Заполнение тега Alt в php

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайте есть код

```
if(!empty($arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['VALUE'])):?>
    <div class="social">
        <?php foreach($arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['VALUE'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <div class="social__item">
                <a href="<?=$value?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="">
                    <img src="<?=\Kosmos\Main\Constant::get('SRC_PATH')?>images/<?=$arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['DESCRIPTION'][$key]?>.svg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endif?>
```

Я хочу, что бы в атрибут Alt подставлялось название картинки, правильно ли я понимаю, что в alt="" я должен вписать либо alt="$value" либо alt="['VALUE']" или туда нужно вписать что-то другое?

Да, я мог бы попробовать методом тыка, но у меня нет возможности сделать бэкап и я боюсь все положить.

Comment: Зачем тебе бэкап, скопируй исходный рабочий кусок кода и экспериментируй. Если что сломается - вставишь рабочий обратно.

Comment: В `$value` у вас будет ссылка на соц. сеть. Попробуйте вставить `$key` - там будет название соц. сети, в каком виде, правда, не известно. `alt="<?=$key?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['VALUE'])):?>
    <div class="social">
        <?php foreach($arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['VALUE'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <div class="social__item">
                <a href="<?=$value?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="">
                    <img src="<?=\Kosmos\Main\Constant::get('SRC_PATH')?>images/<?=$arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['DESCRIPTION'][$key]?>.svg" alt="<?=$arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SOCIAL']['DESCRIPTION'][$key]?>">
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endif?>
```